# Nativescript Angular ActivityIndicator

Tags: angularjs, nativescript

in my Nativescript Angular app i am using an ActivityIndicator, setup as i've seen in the Nativescript Angular docs (the GroceryList example):

```
<ActivityIndicator width="30" height="30" [busy]="refreshing" [visibility]="refreshing ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>
```

if the Component using it i have:

```
export class MyComponent {

  public refreshing = false;

........
}
```

Then i fetch some data from my backend:

```
public onRefreshTap() {
    console.log("onrefreshtap");
    this.refreshing = true;
    this.backend.getData(function (data) { //this.backend is my Service
        this.refreshing = false;
    })
}
```

The problem is that when i put this.refreshing to true, the ActivityIndicator correctly shows. But when bakend request completes (and so, i put this.refreshing=false) the ActivityIndicator does not hides... (and also it seems that its busy property is not updated, it stays in spinning state)..

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to access the `refreshing` property as it has been shown in the sample codes below. It could be a problem of accessing the property inside the callback method of your service.

```
public onRefreshTap() {
    var that = this;
    this.refreshing = true;
    this.backend.getData(function (data) { //this.backend is my Service
        that.refreshing = false;
    })
}
```

or

```
public onRefreshTap() {
    this.refreshing = true;
    this.backend.getData((data) => {
        that.refreshing = false;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be many things: 
 1) The change to false, on the Observable, is not being "seen" by the component.  
     ------ The solution is run the code in a Zone (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html ) 
 2) The backend is returning an error (I don't see it dealing with that in the code). 
     ------ The solution is put a function to deal with the error.  
 3) The callback is not being called. In your code, you're **SENDING a function as a parameter** to the backendService, so maybe the service is not executing it.
     ------ Try using a Promisses or Observables to deal with returned values (you'll have to Google about it, since I'm still learning them my explanation would be the worst). :)

Here's some code that might work:

**my-component.html**

```
 <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isWorking" [visibility]="isWorking?'visible':'collapse'"></ActivityIndicator>
```

**my-component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";

    ...

export class MyComponent {
    isWorking:boolean = false;
    constructor(private backendService: BackendService, 
                private _ngZone: NgZone)
    {
        this.isWorking = false;
    }

    public onRefreshTap() {
        console.log("onrefreshtap");
        this.isWorking = true;
        this.backendService.getData()
            .then( 
                // data is what your BackendService returned after some seconds
                (data) => {
                    this._ngZone.run(
                        () => {
                            this.isWorking = false;

                            // I use to return null when some Server Error occured, but there are smarter ways to deal with that
                            if (!data || data == null || typeof(data)!=='undefined') return; 

                            // here you deal with your data
                        }
                    )
                } 
        );
    }

}
```